# python function project, histo function that return o

Tags: python-3.3

histogram(xs): Given a list of integers named xs, return a string which, when printed, shows a histogram corresponding to the integers. Use small "o" as the display symbol.

- Assume: xs is a list of non-negative integers; xs could be empty.
- Restrictions: none currently stated.
- histogram([3,10,0,5]) → 'ooo\noooooooooo\n\nooooo'
- histogram([]) → ''

This is what I tried:

```
def histogram(xs):
    last = len(xs)
    histo = '' 
    for number in xs: 
        while number > 0: 
            histo += 'o'
            number -= 1 
            last -= 1
            if last == 0:
                if histo == None:
                    return '' 
                return histo
            histo += '\n'
```

Comment: Give it a try yourself, then if it doesn't work come back and paste your code.

Comment: def histogram(xs):
 last = len(xs)
 histo = ''
 for number in xs:
  while number > 0:
   histo += 'o'
   number -= 1
  last -= 1
  if last == 0: 
   if histo == None:
    return ''
   return histo
  histo += '\n'

Comment: please help me if  you can

Answer (score 0):

I may have had your indentation wrong when I edited your question. I had to guess because I was pulling it out of the comment. Also, you might have had an indentation problem. Anyways, this seems to work (It's your original code with proper indentation):

```
def histogram(xs):
    last = len(xs)
    histo = '' 
    for number in xs:
        while number > 0: 
            histo += 'o'
            number -= 1 
        last -= 1
        if last == 0:
            if histo == None:
                return '' 
            return histo
        histo += '\n'
```

Here's a more compact solution:

```
def histogram(xs):
    output = ""
    for number in xs:
        output += "o" * number + "\n"
    return output
```